# Relationship field not parsing

Tags: channel-entries, relationships, entries

I'm trying to pull some data from a relationship child (design) to the parent (packages), but it's simply not parsing anything.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="packages" orderby="date" sort="asc" limit="3"}
    {design:title}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

The above code renders nothing on the page, just white space in the source. The parent entries tag is correct, I have omitted other variables from the example.

I tried including the relationship as a tag pair:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="packages" orderby="date" sort="asc" limit="3"}
    {design}
        {design:title}
    {/design}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Which renders the `{design:title}{/design}` preceded by a digit of which I can't figure out the significance. I don't think it's an entry ID or anything, but it seems to render in place of `{design}`.

Ultimately I'm trying to pull an image from the child's Channel Images field, but I can't seem to access anything.

The site is using EE 2.5.2 (old, I know).

Answer (score 0):

I forgot that back in 2.5.2 the Relationship tag pair was {related_entries}, not the short name of the field itself.

So the correct usage in my example, if anyone needs it, is as follows:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="packages" orderby="date" sort="asc" limit="3"}
    {related_entries id="design"}
        {title}
    {/related_entries}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```